# Blender crashes hard when I undo modal operations

Tags: python, error, operator

I have an operator that when I execute it performs many tasks: It creates primative objects and curves, translates them, sets taper object and materials etc. etc. Some of the tasks are in seperate methods which are called in the execute. The neat thing is that I have set the options like so:

```
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
```

I can then undo ALL the stuff done by this operator and it works really well. BUT...

I recently changed the operator to a modal operator, so that all the tasks are now done when I click in the 3dview where I clicked and I don't have to go back to a panel-button to execute the operator each time. This works nicely, except that When I try to undo, Blender crashes hard with no warning or error message :-( This is regardless of whether or not the modal operator is still running.

But if I do this:

1. start the modal operator (this is done in the execute method of the operator)
2. perform the tasks (clicking in the 3dview)
3. Stop the modal operator (press 'ESC' or other stuff)
4. Do some other operation (like adding a mesh cube, moving an object ect)
5. UNDO (this undos the other operation)
6. UNDO again (this undos the tasks from the modal operator!!!)

So the undo kinda work, but not right after the modal operator :-| I know this is hard to help with without looking around all of my code, but maybe there is some general (maybe even simple **crossing fingers**) stuff I need to be aware of when undoing modal operators (is invoke necessary). Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I trid to replace all the tasks with a  simple:
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
and it still crashed. So it seems likely that it is my modal operator that is set up wrong somehow

EDIT2: I can clarify how the modal operator is set up. I starts with an execute method:

```
class MY_OPERATOR_OT_modal(bpy.types.Operator):        

    bl_idname = "wm.my_modal"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):        
        print("### MODAL STARTED ###")        
        bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].modal_running = True #   
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)        
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

This is called inside a StartModal() function. This function is set as an update when I change a custom enum in a sidebar panel (dropdown menu selector). This means that I need to override the context:

```
def StartFlowModal(self, context):

    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        override = bpy.context.copy()
                        override['area'] = area
                        override['region'] = region
                        override['scene'] = bpy.context.scene   
                        bpy.ops.wm.my_modal(override) # THIS IS WHERE I STORED THE OPERATOR (SEE ABOVE)
    
def modal(self, context, event):

        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE' and event.value == 'PRESS':
                       
            if(not modal_check(context, event)):
                print("### MODAL ABORTED ###")
                PostFlowModal()
                return {'CANCELLED'}                
            
            bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        elif (event.type == 'ESC' or bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].modal_running == False):
            print("### MODAL CANCELED ###")
            PostFlowModal()
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
```

I might be a convoluted way to do modal operator. But it seems to work... except for undo...

Comment: Hello, it's hard to say without seeing any actual code. Could be you are setting a reference somewhere that gets lost in the process and causes a hard crash when trying to retrieve it

Comment: @Gorgious Sure. I was actually adding some code whilst you posted this :-) Is that enough?

Comment: To reiterate either post a link to (or) full code, or make a minimal working example (Which often provides the answer while putting it together). As it is I believe you need to use the `GooberFinkle()` method only if `is_finkle` is true.